# Excel VBA - Shell executable file with multiple arguments

Tags: c#, excel, vba

I can send a string argument `ARGUMENT` in an Excel VBA Shell command to start a c# application:

`Call Shell("""" & filePathExe & """ """ & ARGUMENT & """", vbNormalFocus)`

but is it possible to send an array? It looks like c# applications can receive an array of arguments:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args) { }
```

So my question is - is it possible to send an array via the Shell command or is there a better way to be starting my application via Excel?

Comment: Wait a minute, I've just noticed all the `"` instances... can I separate all my arguments with `"` - YES I can is the answer to that. Now all I need to know is if this stupid question has been asked before. Sure it has.

Comment: I think you would have to make your own function that accepts a paramArray of string arguments and then loops through each element of the paramArray and executes the `Shell` command on them.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? This smells of something that would be better off as `[ComVisible]`.

Comment: @Comintern it really would be much better off as that, I know it would be, but I'm inexperienced in distributing my custom class libraries to other users and getting Excel to be able to use them without a hitch. I can set it all up on my own Computer but seems like a lot of work to be able to distribute this to others successfully. Regasm and all that jazz :/

Answer (score 1):

You could make your own function that takes a paramArray of shell commands and loops through, executing the shell command on each. Like this:

```
Sub ExecuteShell(ParamArray arg() As Variant)
    Dim element As Variant

    For Each element In arg
        Call Shell(element)
    Next element
End Sub
```

Of course, you'll want to maybe trap for "bad" shell arguments.

You would run the above like this:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim arg1, arg2, arg3 As String

    arg1 = "filepath1..."
    arg2 = "filepath2..."
    arg3 = "filepath3..."

    Call ExecuteShell(arg1, arg2, arg3)
End Sub
```

Alternatively, you could structure the function to accept a filepath argument and an array of arguments then all get concatenated together into a single command, like this:

```
Sub ExecuteShell(path As String, ParamArray arg() As Variant)
    Dim element As Variant
    Dim cmd As String

    cmd = path & " " 'insert any pre-arguments charaters

    For Each element In arg
        cmd = cmd & element & ", "
    Next element

    'remove last comma
    cmd = Left(cmd, Len(cmd) - 2)

    Call Shell(cmd)

End Sub
```

Comment: This is basically what I'm doing, although rather than calling shell on each element I was just adding each argument in the array to my string? So e.g. my array contains 1,2,3 and the final command would be `Call Shell ("c:\whatever" "1" "2" "3", vbNormalFocus)`

Comment: Yeah I think your answer is tailored towards running the same application more than once - or will this work on the same instance of the app and just send it multiple arguments one by one.. I need to investigate this.

Comment: Yes, this would run the same application more than once. If you wanted to send multiple arguments in the same command line, I guess you would want to do something similar to the above, but instead "unpack" the array and concat its contents into a single string that you then send to the Shell command.

Comment: @jamheadart based on your comments, I added another suggested version of a custom function to do this...